# How can I get a value froma void method into a toString method?

Tags: java, void

In my class, we have an assignment where we calculate the the volume and surface area of a cube. However, we can only use one instance field. Here's what I have so far...

The first thing was create a class for the cube, as show below.

```
public class cube{
//instance fields
private int sideLength;

//constructors
public cube() {
}

public cube(int height, int length, int width){
    height=sideLength;
    length=sideLength;
     width=sideLength;

}

//methods

public int sideLength(){
    return sideLength;
}

public void surfaceArea(){
    int surfaceArea = (sideLength * sideLength) * 6;
}

public void volume(){
    int volume = sideLength * sideLength * sideLength;
}

public String toString(){
  return "cube[Side Length = "+sideLength+", Volume = , Surface area =]";
}

}
```

Where I am having the most amount of trouble is figuring out the   toString   method. I have to get the values that I've calculated from the `volume` and `surfaceArea` methods.
Currently, the code in the tester class would look like this

```
public class cubeTester{
   public static void main (String[] args){
      cube cube1 = new cube(6, 6, 6);
      cube1.volume();
      cube1.surfaceArea();
      // From here on I have clue what to do
```

So, I'm not even sure if I'm creating the cube correctly, but I need to be able to eventually do something like this: `System.out.println(cube1.toString());`, where the output would be like `Cube[Side Length = 6, Volume = 216, Surface Area = 216]`. However, I'm stuck with trying to actually get the values back from the void methods. Can I have any help with this? Thank you.

Edit: The full requirements for the assignment are as follows;
cube class should contain a default constructor, a constructor that takes in an integer side value, a get method, a method to calculatte the volume, a method to calculate the surface area, and a toString method. The class should contain only one instance field.

I must also create a test file that constructs a cube and contains a method call for all of the methods in the class.

Comment: Your void methods there are non sensical. They compute something and immediately forget the result. You have to change the return type to int and then return the results of the computational.

Comment: why u need to use tostring method

Comment: In Java types are always named in `PascalCase` - `Cube` not `cube`. In addition to @GhostCat's comment - your constructor is also nonsensical.

Comment: As per your constructor height, width, length everything will be **Zero**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the functions to return int instead of void like this:

```
    public int surfaceArea(){
        return ((sideLength * sideLength) * 6);
    }

    public int volume(){
        return (sideLength * sideLength * sideLength);
    }
```

Then, you can write the toString() function like this:

```
   public String toString(){
       return "cube[Side Length = " + sideLength + ", Volume = " + volume()  + ", Surface area = " + surfaceArea() + "]";
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was so confused by what people were meaning by "return the computed result," but I guess it means that my code in the question only calculates the volume and surfaceArea, not actually returns or stores the value. I didn't know you could even use return like that! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to fix your **surfaceArea()** and **volume()** method. It should only return the calculated result.

Then in your **toString()** method, call those two methods to get the volume and area.

In your main method use

```
System.out.println(cube1);
```

to call the toString method. The above line is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(cube1.toString());
```